# Export apk fail

Tags: android

My Project successfully run, but when i export the apk,but crashed it in Prograd-project.txt

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontwarn twitter4j.internal.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.**
-ignorewarnings
```

**But Error**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>         Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>         at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(Unknown Source)
>         at com.student.HTMLCSS.splash_screen.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.student.HTMLCSS.z.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.student.HTMLCSS.z.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>         4 more
>         Caused by: org.apache.poi.hssf.b.do: Unable to determine record types
>         at org.apache.poi.hssf.b.di.a(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.poi.hssf.b.di.(Unknown Source)

**Code**

```
 setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
       progress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgprogress);
    FontHelper.applyFont(this, findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1),
            "helveticaneueltstdlt.ttf");
    helper = new MyDBHelper(this);

   final Integer[] mThumbIds = {

    R.drawable.frame1, R.drawable.frame2, R.drawable.frame3,
            R.drawable.frame4,

    };
if (getLoginPreferences()) { 
  try {
        r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                            progress.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[i]);
            i++;
        if (i >= mThumbIds.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        progress.postDelayed(r, 300); // set to go off again in
        }
    };
    progress.postDelayed(r, 300);
}
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
    public void run() {
            setLoginPreferences("1");
            startActivity(new Intent(splash_screen.this,
                            category_screen.class));
            finish();

        } 
}, 2000);
}
    else
    { 
        start = true;


    try {

            r = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            progress.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[i]);
            i++;
            if (i >= mThumbIds.length) {
                    i = 0;
            }
            progress.postDelayed(r, 3000); // set to go off again in
                            // 3 seconds.
            }
        };
         progress.postDelayed(r, 3000); 
    }

            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        new data().execute();
    } 
}

    void getData() {

        if (!getLoginPreferences()) {   
    try {
                InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(
                        "education.xls");
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);

                // Get first sheet from the workbook
                System.out.println("number of sheet="
                        + workbook.getNumberOfSheets());

                for (int sheetno = 0; sheetno <= 7; sheetno++) {

                    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetno);

                    if (sheetno == 0 || sheetno == 2 || sheetno == 4
                            || sheetno == 6) {
                        Row row;
                        Cell cell;

                        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
                        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                            flag = 1;
                            row = rowIterator.next();

                            // For each row, iterate through each columns
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                cell = cellIterator.next();
                                System.out.println("row index="
                                        + cell.getRowIndex());
                                if (cell.getRowIndex() > 0) {
                                    flag = 0;
                                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                        System.out.println("bool="
                                                + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                                        break;

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                        id = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                        System.out.println("number="
                                                + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        break;

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                        System.out.println("col number="
                                                + cell.getColumnIndex());

                                        System.out.println("string="
                                                + cell.getStringCellValue());

                                        if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
                                            name = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                        } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
                                            uses = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                        } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 3) {
                                            example = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                        }

                                        break;

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                        System.out.println(" ");
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        System.out.println(cell);

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            if (flag == 0) {
                                System.out.println(id + "  " + name + "  "
                                        + uses + "  " + example);
                                if (sheetno == 0)
                                    helper.addContact(0, new Contact(id, name,
                                            uses, example));

                                if (sheetno == 2)
                                    helper.addContact(2, new Contact(id, name,
                                            uses, example));
                                if (sheetno == 4)
                                    helper.addContact(4, new Contact(id, name,
                                            uses, example));
                                if (sheetno == 6)
                                    helper.addContact(6, new Contact(id, name,
                                            uses, example));

                                name = "";
                                uses = "";
                                example = "";
                            }

                        }
                    } else {

                        Row row;
                        Cell cell;
                        flag = 1;
                        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
                        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                            flag = 1;
                            row = rowIterator.next();

                            // For each row, iterate through each columns
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                cell = cellIterator.next();
                                System.out.println("row index="
                                        + cell.getRowIndex());
                                if (cell.getRowIndex() > 0) {
                                    flag = 0;
                                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                        System.out.println("bool="
                                                + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                                        break;

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                        if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0)
                                            ha_id = (int) cell
                                                    .getNumericCellValue();
                                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1)
                                            id = (int) cell
                                                    .getNumericCellValue();

                                        System.out.println("number="
                                                + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        break;

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                        System.out.println("col number="
                                                + cell.getColumnIndex());

                                        System.out.println("string="
                                                + cell.getStringCellValue());

                                        if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
                                            name = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                        } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 3) {
                                            uses = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                        } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 4) {
                                            example = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                        }

                                        break;

                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                        System.out.println(" ");
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        System.out.println(cell);

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            if (flag == 0) {
                                System.out.println(id + "  " + name + "  "
                                        + uses + "  " + example);
                                if (sheetno == 1)
                                    helper.addAttribute(1, new Contact(ha_id,
                                            id, name, uses, example));
                                if (sheetno == 3)
                                    helper.addAttribute(3, new Contact(ha_id,
                                            id, name, uses, example));
                                if (sheetno == 5)
                                    helper.addAttribute(5, new Contact(ha_id,
                                            id, name, uses, example));
                                if (sheetno == 7)
                                    helper.addAttribute(7, new Contact(ha_id,
                                            id, name, uses, example));

                                name = "";
                                uses = "";
                                example = "";

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();    
             }          
        catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
        }   
      } 
        start = false; 
}

private boolean getLoginPreferences() {
    boolean isLogin = false;
    String strUsername = "";

    // try {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN",
            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    strUsername = preferences.getString("TABLE_EXITS", "");

    if (!strUsername.trim().equals("")) {

        isLogin = true;
    } else {
        isLogin = false;
    }

    System.out.println("value in  " + strUsername);
    /*
     * } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception
     * System.out.println("Error at Get login : " + e.toString()); }
     */

    return isLogin;
}

private void setLoginPreferences(String strUsername) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN",
                MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("TABLE_EXITS", strUsername.trim());
        editor.commit();
        System.out.println("sign-up prefrences:" + strUsername);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Error at Set login : " + e.toString());
    }
}

public class data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        setLoginPreferences("1");
    startActivity(new Intent(splash_screen.this, category_screen.class));
        finish();

    }
}
```

Please give me solution for that.

Comment: Provide ur block of code ?

Comment: Exactly at which line you are getting error? Also please format the code.

Comment: Are you getting error while running ur app in device?

Comment: My code is working perfectly but after exported apk run, error show (this error show on before code), i.e in asytask is work. when i getdata() start, error is occur

Comment: @BhoomiDesai Oh you mean without export apk you run directly run in device then perfectly run and when export your apk and run that exported apk you got error.

Comment: ya, Definitely . so i can't understand this problem .

Comment: @BhoomiDesai But can you please format your above code too complected to read. And yes are you belongs to amd?

Comment: @BhoomiDesai If you know gujarati then clarify me very easily

Comment: I think You can understand this code. i can't understand why this error occur when i export the apk

Comment: @BhoomiDesai Just go my profile from there you can get my id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add in proguard-project.txt

   -keep public class  java.awt.**
{
 public protected *;
}
-keep public class  javax.swing.**
{
 public protected *;
}
-keep public class  javax.imageio.**
{
 public protected *;
 }
-keep public class  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
{
 public protected *;
}
-keep public class  java.rmi.UnexpectedException
{
 public protected *;
 }

-dontwarn twitter4j.internal.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.swing.**
-dontwarn javax.imageio.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-dontwarn java.rmi.UnexpectedException

-libraryjars  /libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar
-libraryjars  /libs/poi-3.7.jar
```